# Wordpress: display post count from category and date

Tags: wordpress

I have tried so many variations of code to achieve this, so any help would be appreciated..

I want to display a post count for each category, but also from a certain time frame.

For example the number of posts for category 1 this week.

The code I have to get the post count is

```
<?php
$chosen_id = 1;
$thisCat = get_category($chosen_id);
echo $thisCat->count;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could just write a SQL query yourself to get the row count from the wp_posts table which have a certain category ID.

Answer (score 0):

As with most all things programming related, there are a number of different ways to accomplish this, but here's one solution:

```
<?php
    $current_year = date('Y');
    $week = date('W');
    $category = 1;
    $countposts = get_posts("year=$current_year&w=$week&category=$category");
    echo 'There are ' . count($countposts) . ' posts in category ' . $category;
?>
```

We first get the current year, then the current week number (note: weeks start on Monday) and then get all the posts for the specified category in the current week. The posts are now contained in the `$countposts` variable where we can count them.

More information on php's `date()` function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

This solution could easily be abstracted out into it's own function within `functions.php` as well.